# PySide: emit() signal with a list as a parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals, pyside, emit

I'm new to GUI application development in Python. I'm using PySide to develop a GUI. I need help with passing parameters across two threads. I know how to use custom Signals and Slot mechanism.

I wish to transmit a `list` from my `second thread` to my `main thread`.

Python pseudo code (I wish to send a list `correction_values` from my `second thread` to the `main thread`):

```
---main thread----
self.connect(self.Tests_Start, SIGNAL("Test1_Passed()"), self.StartThread_Test1_Passed, Qt.DirectConnection)
def StartThread_Test1_Passed(self, values):
   for value in values:
      self.textEdit1.insertPlainText(value)
      self.textEdit1.insertPlainText(',')
```

-

```
---second thread----
def Tests()
   self.emit(SIGNAL("Test1_Passed()"), correction_values) # Is this way possible?
```

Comment: [Signals and Slots in PySide](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide) might also be interesting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Communication between threads in PySide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823112/communication-between-threads-in-pyside)

Answer (score 3):

You can use new-style emit & signal. It's easy than old-style. Your just create signal object;

```
class QCustomWidget (QtCore.QWidget):

    # create a new signal name 'Test1_Passed' and argument 'object' (Anything)
    Test1_Passed = QtCore.Signal(object)

    def __init__ (self):
        .
        .
```

Next, connect signal by use 'connect';

```
self.Test1_Passed.connect(self.StartThread_Test1_Passed)
```

check your function is pass variable;

```
@QtCore.Slot(object)
def StartThread_Test1_Passed (self, values):
    .
    .
```

Last, use 'emit' signal;

```
correction_values = ['1', '2', '3'] # List data-type
self.Test1_Passed.emit(correction_values)
```

Also you can read this [document](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide) to more information.

Answer (score -1):

You can emit a list via a signal by using Signal((list, )), yet it doesn't work when you add typing. So Signal((List[type],)) doesn't work, I am afraid.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).